# Default collation not working?

Tags: postgresql, collation

I don't understand why the default collation on my psqlserver 11 instance returns a different result than using with explicit collation.

Details:

```
show LC_CTYPE;        -- de-AT
show LC_COLLATE;      -- de-AT
```

When I use the default collation I get an unexpected output:

```
demo=# SELECT unnest(array['a','B', 'A']) order by 1;
 unnest 
--------
 A
 B
 a
(3 rows)
```

When I add the default collation explicitly, I get the expected output:

```
demo=# SELECT unnest(array['a','B', 'A']) collate "de-AT-x-icu" ORDER BY 1;
 unnest 
--------
 a
 A
 B
(3 rows)
```

The collation `de-AT-x-icu` uses exactly the default values for `LC_COLLATE` and `LC_COLTYPE` shown above:

```
SELECT collname, collcollate, collctype
FROM pg_collation
where collname like '%de-AT%';

  collname   | collcollate | collctype 
-------------+-------------+-----------
 de-AT-x-icu | de-AT       | de-AT
```

So I think both queries should return the same result: What am I missing?

More info:

- postgresql version `11.5`
- OS inside the Docker container:
  `Linux 8660fb4cef84 4.9.184-linuxkit #1 SMP Tue Jul 2 22:58:16 UTC 2019 x86_64 Linux`

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Linux inside docker (I've updated the question)

Comment: `de-AT` is unusual as a locale name in Linux (`de_AT.UTF-8` would be the usual form). Can you show the result of `locale -a` from the shell?

Comment: @DanielVérité: `locale -a` does not work in this docker image (`locale not found`): But the explicit collation also uses `de-AT`, as we can see from the `pg_collation` table - and the example using this collation works,: so it must be correct, right?

Comment: @TmTron: the `de-AT-x-icu` collation you're looking at in pg_collation is not your default collation, because the default collation (the one specified in CREATE DATABASE) *must* be a libc collation, not an ICU one.

Comment: You need to check if `de-AT` is indeed a valid LC_COLLATE for your operating system (docker image in fact) and that it sorts as you expect, independently of Postgres. If you don't have any tool in the docker subsystem to do that, personally I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: @DanielVérité: maybe we can approach this from the other side: we know that `collate "de-AT-x-icu"` works: so how can I find out which `LC_COLLATE` string to use? I thought that `pg_collation.collctype ` is the correct way. If not, then why does the explict collate query work?

Comment: This approach is a dead end because `de-AT-x-icu` is an ICU collation, and unfortunately as such it cannot be used as the default collation. This is a current limitation of the ICU integration in PostgreSQL as of version 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me guess: you are using Alpine Linux, which uses `musl` as its C library, which uses ICU collations by default.

[It is known](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58135353/6464308) that the collations in Alpine Linux don't work quite as they should, which is the cause of the problem. I am not sure if that is PostgreSQL's fault or not.

At any rate, you should use a different Linux distribution that uses `glibc`.

Answer (score 0):

After reading lots of posts, docs and the great comments an answers here, I'll try to sum up the case (please leave a comment if something is wrong).

It turned out that @Laurenz Albe is right: I was using the docker image `timescale/timescaledb:1.5.0-pg11` ([Docker-Hub link](https://hub.docker.com/r/timescale/timescaledb)).
I didn't think, that this could be based on alpine, because those images usually end in `-alpine`. But since this is only a convention, I should have checked their [Dockerfile](https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile#L89)...

It seems that currently there is only the alpine-based timescale-db image available on dockerhub: see [timescaledb-docker#78](https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb-docker/issues/78)

The docs on [docker-hub postgres](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) mention that:

> **postgres:-alpine**
>   This image is based on the popular Alpine Linux project,.. The main **caveat** to note is that it does use **musl** libc instead of glibc and friends, so certain software might run into issues depending on the depth of their libc requirements.

So the docker-image uses [musl](https://www.musl-libc.org/) which has some [differences to glibc](https://wiki.musl-libc.org/functional-differences-from-glibc.html). One important difference is that the os-command `locale` is not available.
When starting the docker-container with the [init-db parameters](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/app-initdb.html): e.g. 
`POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS=--lc-collate=de-AT --lc-ctype=de-AT`, there are warnings on the console:

```
running bootstrap script ... ok
performing post-bootstrap initialization ... sh: locale: not found
2019-11-04 16:48:16.725 UTC [26] WARNING:  no usable system locales were found
ok
```

So the db actually told us correctly that the provided locale/collation is ignored.

What is quite confusing, is that the following statements still show the values set by the initdb parameters:

```
show LC_CTYPE;    -- de-AT
show LC_COLLATE;  -- de-AT
```

But these are not used per default as @Daniel Vérité pointed out in a comment.

By looking at the [postgres-alpine Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/11/alpine/Dockerfile#L113) we can see that the image is built with [icu](http://site.icu-project.org/home) support enabled (`--with-icu`).
So when we use an icu collation directly in a query (e.g. `collate "de-AT-x-icu"`) it will work, because this uses the statically linked icu lib and does not need to ask the os dependent glib-c.

Comment: There is also the timescale/timescaledb:1.5.0-pg11-bitnami Docker image that uses glibc

Comment: @FeikeSteenbergen Thanks for the hint. Actually I've already found that, but cannot make it work: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/252657/how-to-use-timescale-bitnami-image-on-windows