# How to use timescale-bitnami image on Windows?

Tags: postgresql, docker, timescaledb, bitnami

Since there are [issues with collations](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/252482/default-collation-not-working) in the default alpine-based timescaledb images, I tried to use the [bitnami-image](https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb-docker/tree/master/bitnami). But I get an error on startup.

```
docker run ^
-p 5432:5432 ^
-v tsdb-bitnami:/bitnami/postgresql ^
--env POSTGRES_USER=tsdbu ^
--env POSTGRES_DB=tsdbu ^
--env POSTGRES_PASSWORD=tsdbu ^
--name timeseriesdb ^
timescale/timescaledb:1.5.0-pg11-bitnami
```

This fails with:

```
ERROR:  permission denied to create extension "timescaledb"
HINT:  Must be superuser to create this extension.
```

Is there some other parameter that we must pass? i.e. I've tried `POSTGRESQL_POSTGRES_PASSWORD` (ref= [bitnami postgres docs](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-postgresql#environment-variables-aliases)), but this did also not work.

Versions:

- Windows 10 64-bit
- Docker version 19.03.4, build 9013bf5
- Timescale container: timescale/timescaledb:1.5.0-pg11-bitnami

Full Output:

```
postgresql 12:31:34.41
postgresql 12:31:34.41 Welcome to the Bitnami postgresql container
postgresql 12:31:34.41 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-postgresql
postgresql 12:31:34.41 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-postgresql/issues
postgresql 12:31:34.42 Send us your feedback at containers@bitnami.com
postgresql 12:31:34.42
postgresql 12:31:34.42 INFO  ==> ** Starting PostgreSQL setup **
postgresql 12:31:34.45 INFO  ==> Validating settings in POSTGRESQL_* env vars..
postgresql 12:31:34.46 INFO  ==> Initializing PostgreSQL database...
postgresql 12:31:34.46 INFO  ==> postgresql.conf file not detected. Generating it...
postgresql 12:31:34.47 INFO  ==> pg_hba.conf file not detected. Generating it...
postgresql 12:31:35.67 INFO  ==> Starting PostgreSQL in background...
postgresql 12:31:36.14 INFO  ==> Creating user tsdbu
postgresql 12:31:36.15 INFO  ==> Grating access to "tsdbu" to the database "tsdbu"
postgresql 12:31:36.16 INFO  ==> Configuring replication parameters
postgresql 12:31:36.18 INFO  ==> Configuring fsync
postgresql 12:31:36.18 INFO  ==> Loading custom scripts...
postgresql 12:31:36.19 INFO  ==> Loading user's custom files from /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d ...
postgresql 12:31:36.19 INFO  ==> Starting PostgreSQL in background...
ERROR:  permission denied to create extension "timescaledb"
HINT:  Must be superuser to create this extension.
postgresql 12:31:36.20 INFO  ==> Stopping PostgreSQL...
```

Comment: "It is possible to change the user that PostgreSQL will use to execute the init scripts. To do so, use the following environment variables" -- that maybe?

Comment: The POSTGRES_USER is documented by bitname to be a regular user, which indeed cannot install timescaledb.

https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-postgresql#creating-a-database-user-on-first-run

As a workaround for now, specify `POSTGRES_USER` to be postgres, that will work, afterwards you can create a database and user manually.

Created an issue to have this addressed here:
https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb-docker/issues/79